# There is a type named thread in lua. Does anyone know something of this?

Tags: multithreading, lua, types

I was reading the lua manual (looking for something) and I found out that there is a type named thread in lua. Of wath I read it represents independent threads of execution and it is used to implement coroutines.

Here is the link to the place I read it.
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2

How do I use these threads? Are there any good tutorials?
I have googled and had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to look at the [Co-routine tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CoroutinesTutorial) and see if that is helpful for you.